# Jetpack Compose View.GONE alternative

Tags: android, kotlin, automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose, ui-automation

Is there any compose View.GONE alternative, that is not a condition?
I need a button to be still findable and clickable by an automated test but not by user.

So using a condition is not a solution for me.

```
if (false) {
    Button(
        onClick = { onDebugClicked() },
        modifier = Modifier.addResourceIdWithPackageNameAndContentDesc("buttonDebug")
    ) {
        // this does not create the button at all so it cannot be clicked by a script
    }
}
```

Also I do not want it invisible by using alpha, I want it GONE

I also tried to shrink it so it has no size, but that did not work either

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(0dp)
        .wrapContentSize()
        .addResourceIdWithPackageNameAndContentDesc("buttonDebug")
        .clickable { onDebugClicked() },
) {
    // nothing, empty invisible clickable view for automated testing
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a matter of replacing `if (false)` with `if (isAutomatedTest)`, where you set `isAutomatedTest` based on something like `BuildConfig` or an `Intent` extra or something?

Comment: I mean it probably could and should be done this way but seems like a lot of extra work

Comment: but it seems like I will have to do that

Comment: So I decided to launch the code with an intent instead

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an official way to do this as its preferred that you'd use an if conditional. Creating modifiers and composables that are not visible to a user just creates unnecessary work for the compiler and will slow down the UI unnecessarily.

But, in case you REALLY want to do this, you can create a layout Modifier that just returns the size as 0,0.

```kotlin
fun Modifier.gone(gone: Boolean) = if (!gone) this else this.then(Gone)

private object Gone : LayoutModifier {
    override fun MeasureScope.measure(
        measurable: Measurable,
        constraints: Constraints
    ): MeasureResult {
        return layout(0, 0) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and then analyzed the screen with Appium Studio and I could not find the element whatsoever. However I decided to launch the code with an intent instead of a click.